# Draw bounding box around a sequence of contours

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I am trying to put a bounding box around a sequence of contours like the following. A top contour and a bottom contour
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuRnV.png)
I wrote the following basic code and this was the result [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMQBQ.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('light2.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0, 0, 46), (179, 255, 255))

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

try: hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
except: hierarchy = []

height, width, _ = img.shape
min_x, min_y = width, height
max_x = max_y = 0

for contour, hier in zip(contours, hierarchy):
  (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
  min_x, max_x = min(x, min_x), max(x+w, max_x)
  min_y, max_y = min(y, min_y), max(y+h, max_y)
  if w > 80 and h > 80:
      cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

if max_x - min_x > 0 and max_y - min_y > 0:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (min_x, min_y), (max_x, max_y), (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

I am kind of struggling with the logic when there are other contours in the environment like in [image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exo7R.jpg). And still want to put a bounding box around the top and bottom contour detection only (something like this [image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oamRk.png)). But with the current code, it puts the bounding box like this [image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9nQ4.jpg). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Get the bounding boxes of each and then get the min x, max x and min y, max y values. Those are the corners of the bounding box around the two.

Comment: But there will be more bounding boxes in the picture. How to exclude that?

Comment: Filter the contours by their bounding box locations to keep only the ones you want, then do the min and max as above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explain computer what you want using tools that you have. I suggest use `threshold` -> `connectedComponents` -> `filter wrong bboxes` -> `find 2 bbox with same X position and ≈ area (not implemented)` -> `union bboxes`

[image: result.jpg]

Code example:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


def drawStats(img: np.array, arr: np.array):
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        w = arr[i, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]
        h = arr[i, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]
        l = arr[i, cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT]
        t = arr[i, cv2.CC_STAT_TOP]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (l, t), (l+w,t+h), (20, 0, 255), 3)

def filterStats(arr: np.array) -> np.array:
    result = []
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        w = arr[i, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]
        h = arr[i, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]
        if w > h * 4:
            result.append(arr[i])
        
    result = np.array(result)
    return result

img = cv2.imread("/Users/alex/Downloads/exo7R.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
_, img2 = cv2.threshold(img, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

comp = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img2, connectivity=8)
debugImg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
stats = filterStats(comp[2])
drawStats(debugImg, stats)

cv2.imshow("threshold", img2)
cv2.imshow("found components", debugImg)
cv2.waitKey()
```